# Distributional limit.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

I`m preparing for an exam and I have this question:
how can I find the distributional limit for something like for $f\in L^1 (R)$ :

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \int^{\infty}_0 f(x) \cos \left(t \sqrt x\right) dx $$

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \int^{\infty}_0 f(x) \cos\left(t \sqrt x\right) dx $$

Thanks.

Comment: is this a question from a textbook?

Comment: The Functional-Analysis and Analysis tags are appropriate here.  But how is this question related to Distribution-Theory or Harmonic Analysis?

Comment: no, it`s not from a textbook

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|f(x)\cos(t\sqrt x)|\le |f(x)|$.  Inasmuch as $\int_0^\infty |f(x)|\,dx<\infty$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to 0}\int_0^\infty f(x)\cos(t\sqrt x)\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \lim_{t\to 0}\left(f(x)\cos(t\sqrt x)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$

So, the distributional limit is the classical limit

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\cos(t\sqrt x)=1$$

---

Note that since $\int_0^\infty |f(x)|\,dx<\infty$, then $\int_0^\infty x|f(x^2)|\,dx<\infty$ also.  That is to say, $xf(x^2)\in L^1$.

Noting that $\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_0^\infty f(x)\cos(t\sqrt{x})\,dx=2\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_0^\infty xf(x^2)\cos(tx)\,dx$, the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma guarantees that

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_0^\infty f(x)\cos(t\sqrt{x})\,dx=0$$

Thus, the distributional limit is

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\cos(t\sqrt x)\sim 0$$

Comment: Nice one @Mark ... two very important concepts explained in just a few lines...(+1)

Comment: why distribution theory is not appropriate? these both are distributions and distribution theory isn`t a part of Harmonic analysis? something more, we didn`t use any properties of distribution here, why?

Comment: To evaluate the limits, we relied on results from classical functional analysis.